# how to copy string into another variable

Tags: cobol

Create a program that will ask the user to enter a word. Check if the word is a palindrome.

WHEN I TYPE LOL IT SAYS IT IS NOT A PALINDROME. PLS HELP ME

```
   DISPLAY "Enter a word to check if it is a Palindrome: "
        ACCEPT WS-STR1

        MOVE FUNCTION REVERSE(WS-STR1)TO WS-STR2
        DISPLAY WS-STR1
        DISPLAY WS-STR2
   IF  WS-STR1(1:1) = WS-STR2(15:1)
   AND WS-STR1(2:1) = WS-STR2(14:1)
   AND WS-STR1(3:1) = WS-STR2(13:1)
   AND WS-STR1(4:1) = WS-STR2(12:1)
   AND WS-STR1(5:1) = WS-STR2(11:1)
   AND WS-STR1(6:1) = WS-STR2(10:1)
   AND WS-STR1(7:1) = WS-STR2(9:1)

           DISPLAY "A PALINDROME! "
   ELSE
           DISPLAY "NOT A PALINDROME "
       END-IF.
```

Comment: Why do you reverse it then check each character and limit it to be only 16 characters?

Also, of course it will say false, because `LOL` isn't 16 characters, so first character will be `L`, and last character, which is specifically `16` will be who knows what.

You should use `is equal to` operator to compare string and it's reversed version, not whatever *that* thing is.

Comment: Definitely no need to hold the string in two variables. Reversing the string doesn't change anything but the indexes of each letter.

Answer (score 3):

Two things.  First if you're going to reverse the string please remove white space or it will never match.  Second.  A palindrome reversed equals itself so there's no need to compare byte by byte as string a = reversed string a

```
   DISPLAY "Enter a word to check if it is a Palindrome: "
   ACCEPT WS-STR1

   MOVE FUNCTION REVERSE(FUNCTION TRIM(WS-STR1)) TO WS-STR2
   DISPLAY WS-STR1
   DISPLAY WS-STR2

   IF WS-STR1 = WS-STR2
      DISPLAY "A PALINDROME! "                          
   ELSE             
      DISPLAY "NOT A PALINDROME "             
   END-IF

   STOP RUN.
```